# performing a remote shutdown and login from linux to windows

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote, rdesktop

Here is a situation I am on a Linux machine and I have to access a windows xp machine to which I can connect with rdesktop.The problem is Windows XP machine is remotely located and to be able to do a rdesktop I first physically go to the windows machine and login, I come back to my chair open the terminal on my linux machine and do an rdesktop, then windows property dialog opens and asks to disconnect other user then I can login.If I do a remote restart of the windows machine as per instructions here http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sysprop_to_perform_a_remote_reboot.mspx?mfr=true

to be able to again login via rdesktop I have to physically go the the said windows xp machine and do a login there only then I am able to do an rdesktop.
What I want is after each reboot rather than going each time and logging in as some dummy user coming back to my chair and then doing an rdesktop is it possible that I escape this 
dummy user login which I have to physically do again and again to be able to do an rdesktop.If I do not do it the rdkestop can not connect to Windows machine.
I hope I made my question clear.If not please let me know.
I am using Windows XP and Ubuntu here.

Answer (score 0):

You can stick SSHD for Windows on, if you're that way inclined :).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very chaotic, and I'm not sure what you are asking. However, to answer the question in the subject of your post, you can shut down a remote Windows computer with the following command. You will need the Samba client commands installed.

```
net rpc shutdown -f -I <host> -W <domain> -U <username>
```

If you want to reboot the computer instead of shutdown, then append the `-r` option.

If you are having problems with making a remote desktop connection to Windows XP, you should ask your question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Powershell installed in Linux you can use [`Stop-Computer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-computer?view=powershell-7.1) to shut down a windows machine remotely.

```powershell
Stop-Computer -ComputerName remotehost
```